# How can a Ajax/jQuery script show 2+ dependent dropdown box entries within one Form url?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I am developing a simple form prototype that contains 4 entries in PythonAnywhere (Python 3.7 + Django):

1. PinID (Independent, simple manual number entry)
2. Region (Independent Dropdown Box)
3. Name (Region-Dependent Dropdown Box)
4. Source (Name-Dependent Dropdown Box)

What shows up in the Name box is dependent on the Region box, and what shows up in the Source box is dependent on the Name box. So ultimately, the Source Box is dependent on the Region box (If A, then B. If B, then C. So C is dependent on A). To note, if the Region or Name box is blank, their respective dependents are blank.

As my current code is written (which is likely wrong), I can only get my Name box to autopopulate correctly. The Source box remains blank, but it does indeed autopopulate correctly after I refresh the page. However, I intend to keep the form all in one url. I refer to two other .html files to "insert" themselves into the form's .html file without refreshing the page. In the jQuery script, I put the identical segment of code for the second dependent dropdown box under the success function of the first dependent dropdown box, which might be my issue.

So, I presume my coding issue is initiating two different url references within one jQuery script. Does anyone know if I can correct my jQuery script to reference both urls? I included my relevant Django files for reference and if I am overlooking an error in those particular files.

For reference, I have based my work using [this tutorial.](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html) However, this tutorial only worked with one dependent dropdown box.

**form.html (Ajax/jQuery)**

```
<form method="post" id="nameForm" data-names-url="{% url 'ajax_load_names' %}" data-sources-url="{% url 'ajax_load_sources' %}" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
      {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
    <a href="{% url 'name_changelist' %}">Nevermind</a>
  </form>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $("#id_region").change(function () {
      var url = $("#nameForm").attr("data-names-url");
      var regionId = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
          'region': regionId
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $("#id_name").html(data);
            $("#id_source").change(function () {
              var url = $("#nameForm").attr("data-sources-url");
              var nameId = $(this).val();
              $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                  'name': nameId
                },
                success: function (data) {
                  $("#id_source").html(data);
                }
              });
            });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

**name_dropdown_list_options.html**

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for name in names %}
<option value="{{ name.pk }}">{{ name.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

**source_dropdown_list_options.html**

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for source in sources %}
<option value="{{ source.pk }}">{{ source.source }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

**forms.py**

```
class RequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields = ('pinid', 'region', 'name', 'source')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].queryset = Name.objects.none()
        self.fields['source'].queryset = Source.objects.none()

        if 'region' in self.data:
            try:
                region_id = int(self.data.get('region'))
                self.fields['name'].queryset = Name.objects.filter(region_id=region_id).order_by('region')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass  # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty Name queryset
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['name'].queryset = self.instance.region.name_set.order_by('region')

        if 'name' in self.data:
            try:
                name_id = int(self.data.get('name'))
                self.fields['source'].queryset = Source.objects.filter(name_id=name_id).order_by('name')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass  # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty Source queryset
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['source'].queryset = self.instance.name.source_set.order_by('source')
```

**models.py**

```
class Region(models.Model):
    region = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.region

class Name(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Source(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Name, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.source

class Request(models.Model):
    pinid = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.ForeignKey(Name, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __int__(self):
        return self.pinid
```

**views.py**

```
class NameCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Request
    form_class = RequestForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('name_changelist')

def load_names(request):
    region_id = request.GET.get('region')
    names = Name.objects.filter(region_id=region_id).order_by('region')
    return render(request, '/home/name_dropdown_list_options.html', {'names': names})

def load_sources(request):
    name_id = request.GET.get('name')
    sources = Source.objects.filter(name_id=name_id).order_by('name')
    return render(request, '/home/source_dropdown_list_options.html', {'sources': sources})
```

Answer (score 0):

First move change your form.html javascript, so that the `$("#id_source").change(function ()` 
is on the same level as the name change function. I suppose otherwise it will never be called:

forms.html javascript

```
<script>
    $("#id_region").change(function () {
        var url = $("#nameForm").attr("data-names-url");
        var regionId = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: {
                'region': regionId
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#id_name").html(data);
            }
        });
    });

    $("#id_source").change(function () {
        var url = $("#nameForm").attr("data-sources-url");
        var nameId = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: {
                'name': nameId
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#id_source").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I would start with a much simpler design to fetch the names and sources. Remove the complete init of your request form so that the standard init gives you all values for the names and sources. You will need them because the form validates against these values and if its empty none of them will be valid. You can remove the values then with a little javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id_region").html("---"); // or whatever your null value will be
    $("#id_source").html("---");
});
```

To get the values of names and sources you need to view functions:

```
def load_names(request, region_id):
    names = Name.objects.filter(region__id=region_id).order_by('region')
    html = ''
    for name in names:
        html += '<option value="{id}">{name}</option>\n'.format(id=name.id, name=name.name)
    return HttpResponse(html)


def load_sources(request, name_id):
    sources = Source.objects.filter(name__id=name_id).order_by('region')
    html = ''
    for source in sources:
        html += '<option value="{id}">{source}</option>\n'.format(id=name.id, source=source.source)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

If this works fine you can change them to templatetags, if you want

At last you need the proper url definitions:

```
path('load_names', views.load_names, name='load-names'),
path('load_sources', views.load_sources, name='load-sources'),
```

Pass these to your view form.

Comment: ... and if you don't want to implement by yourself, django_autocomplete_light does support chained selection fields: https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form